# EVAL(). Is this dangerous?

Tags: python, python-2.7, internationalization, eval, rm

Well, almost everybody out there say that `eval` is evil, and that's true for the 99% of situations...BUT I'm here to ask about some piece of code I've wrote that uses `eval`, SO, Is this dangerous?

I tried to sanitize data as most as possible, while keeping the original funtionality, but this makes use of `eval` and something can go wrong:

```
import os

try:
    if os.environ["LANG"].rstrip('''\n''')[5:] == ".UTF-8":
        Language = str(os.environ["LANG"].rstrip('''\n''').rstrip(os.environ["LANG"].rstrip('''\n''')[5:]))
        eval (str("LP." + Language + "()"))
    else:
        raise Exception("Not an UTF-8 locale")
except KeyError:
    LP.Fallback()
except AttributeError:
    LP.Fallback()
```

First of all, this code is supposed to run under UNIX and derivatives.

Wrote in python2.7.

What this does is to call some methods inside the `LP` class.

I've alredy tried to mess up my PC trying to change my `LANG` system variable to any string that could harm my PC, like `rm -rf /` or similars, but, because my code removes the last 5 characters of the `LANG` var & adds `LP.` at the start and `()` at the end , it results like this, without mentioning that it checks from the start if last 5 characters of the string are `UTF-8`, but if I delete that condition this should be the "harmful" command:

`LP.rm -r()`

Until now, I've noted that any command longer than 5 characters won't be able to bypass the "remove last 5 characters" line of code, and the added `LP.` & `()` should suffice to neutralize any attempt of harm.

Till now, I'll keep the ".UTF-8" to avoid any critical error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any reason for `eval` here at all.

You're trying to get the method on `LP` that corresponds to the LANGUAGE setting. So, you can use `getattr`:

```
meth = getattr(LP, Language)
result = meth()
```

Note there's no need to do the `rstrip` stuff so many times:

```
lang = os.environ["LANG"].rstrip('''\n''')
if lang.endswith(".UTF-8"):
    ...
```

Comment: This worked as it should. Didn't know about `endswitch` & `getattr`, things work better with these. Such a fast response, Thanks!

P.S: Is `eval` 100% replaceable with some any other command? Or are there sometimes when it's the only one solution?

Comment: I'm sure there are times when it's the only solution, otherwise it wouldn't be in the language at all. They should be fairly rare though.